# What's the meaning of "in rapid order"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

> I will get it solved **in rapid order.**

—Statement By D. Trump in a [YouTube Short](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/jcNzoONhrmE)

What's the meaning of the phrase?

Comment: Give a link to the source.  As written it is ungrammatical.  Trump does make grammar errors in speech. So you need to link to show if it is his or your mistake.  You might add what you think it means, given the full context of what Trump was talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In rapid order" normally means "quickly one after another"

> The neurons fire in rapid order.

Here Trump just means "quickly".

> I will get it solved quickly.

He is probably mixing up idioms like "[in good order](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/in%20good%20order)" or "[in short order](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-short-order)" But he has muddled up the figure of speech. It isn't idiomatic to so "in rapid order" in this sense.

Comment: I'm quite used to 'in short order' meaning 'rapidly or quickly'.

Comment: Yes, in speech, such figures of speech often get muddled.  Skilled public speakers are able to edit out many such mistakes - but Trump is not much good a public speaking.